# Dynamically adding elements to a form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

My goal is to have a form where I fill in some details and then I can hit 'add question' which is a link that should dynamically add a question.

i.e.

---

Date:
Name:
Description:

**Add a Question**

Create

---

my **_form.html.haml** starts off as such as such (this form is under views/interviews since my goal is to be able to add questions to an interview. However, questions can be used independently of interviews as well)

```
= form_for ([:posting, @interview]) do |ff|<br>
     - if @interview.errors.any?

   . . . (more fields) . . .

.field{:id => "overall_questions"} 
    =link_to "Add a Question", new_question_path, :remote => true
    %br/
    %br/

.field{:id => "individual_questions"} 
    =ff.label :whyyy
    =ff.fields_for  :questions, @interview.questions do |builder|
        = render :partial => "question_fields" 
    %br/  
    %br/

.actions
    = ff.submit
```

**_question_fields.html.haml**

```
.fields{:id => "question#{builder.object.id}"}
    =ff.label :content, "Question"
    =link_to "Remove", question_path(builder.object.id), :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
    %br/
    =ff.text_area :content, :rows => 3
```

the :remote => true (from _form.html.haml) gets directed to my **questions_controller.rb**

```
def new

    @question = Question.new
    respond_to :js

end
```

this links to my **new.js.erb** file under views/questions

```
$('#individual_questions').clone().appendTo($('#overall_questions'))
```

The thing is, I'm not quite sure how to call the _question_fields.html.haml. I know the js.erb file works because I've been able to run alert boxes when clicking 'Add a question' and it also currently appends the Whyyy from the field with id individual questions.

Comment: First, welcome to the site! Second, don't worry about your newness - just focus on asking good questions, as outlined in the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - that's all that really matters. Third, I've edited your question to get it down to the parts that really matter. Stick to the relevant information, and you'll be fine. Lastly, you don't need to put your tags in the question itself - that's just duplicating the list of tags, which controls who sees your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is outlined in the following episode of RailsCasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2

As far as the `.haml` question, you should be able to modify the example in the episode to figure that part out. So long as it's name follows the convention (and on quick glance it looks like it does), it should work without too much trouble.